# Building a custom xbmc distro with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, xbmc

How could you use Ubuntu to create your own distro of XBMC (ex. Boxee Plex)? Is there a site (I checked XBMC's wiki and found nothing) that tells you how to do this?

Comment: no, no. thats not my question. My question is how to do it with XBMC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the answer in the development of [XBMCbuntu](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=XBMCbuntu), which is now the [recommended live demo-and-install media for XBMC](http://xbmc.org/natethomas/2012/03/24/xbmc-11-0-eden/), as of XBMC 11, “Eden”.

If you are expecting a straightforward how-to procedure, I think you will be disappointed. XBMCbuntu is the result of a lot of complex work by a lot of people, and the best way to understand how it is put together is to examine the [source code repository](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xbmc`

For a thorough installation guide for lots of media stuff check [this question on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36948/home-entertainment-dvr-solutions) AskUbuntu.  The accepted answer covers a lot of the multimedia application installation and skinning.

If the question isn't how do I install xmbc, but how do I make a respin you should check out turnkeylinux tools or remastersys.